# Ruby: Access mysql data by column name?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to get access the data in a result via the column name instead of the column position?

For example, if I have a column that is called `name`, I want to do something like:

```
result = db.query "select * from employees"
row  = result.fetch_row
puts row['name']
```

instead of looking up the table schema, manually, determining that `name` is the 3rd column and then doing:

```
puts row[2]
```

I've searched on google and can't seem to find the right search phrase to use!

Thanks!

Comment: You could try puts result.inspect to see the structure of the object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result.each_hash do |row|
  puts row['name']
end
```